# NodeJS server not accessible from outside

Tags: node.js, iptables

I deployed a nodejs server in Rackspace and can be accessed internally, like using:

`curl http://127.0.0.1:8080`

However, it can't be accessed from the outside (the internet) even if I do this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp  --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Simple server\n');
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you have to use

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp  --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

for the outgoing rule (not `dport`). Apart from that, maybe there's an earlier rule that blocks the traffic? Try `iptables -L`.

Answer (score 9):

I think you should try not specifying an IP.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Simple server\n');
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/');
```

Comment: tried it just now, but still don't work. Is this what you do in your server. How do you setup iptables for your nodejs server?

Answer (score 4):

Faced same issue while configuring Nodejs on local virtual machine. Try below steps,

> 1. Use **listen(PORT)** in JS code, in your case *PORT will be 8080*
> 2. Add below entry in server machine:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed my problem using ubuntu machine.