# I can't access my node.js server on my AWS EC2 isntance from the outside

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run a basic node.js server,

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('hello world!\n');
}).listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```

However when I run it and go to http://x.x.x.x:3000/ the page doesn't load.

I tried the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017674/nodejs-server-not-accessible-from-outside) but that didn't work either. And changing the host to `127.0.0.1` or the server ip or emitting it doesn't fix it either.

I've also followed [this guide](http://catchvar.com/nodejs-server-and-web-sockets-on-amazon-ec2-w) that says to proxy requests with haproxy. But that did not work either.

Is there something in the security tab I have to enable/disable?

Edit: The problem was I was using the wrong IP. The IP changes when the instance is restarted.

Answer (score 7):

Create a rule to open port 3000 in the security group associated with your ec2 instance.
It can be done through the command line tools or through the web console, which is more straightforward. If you didn't specify a security group when creating the instance it will be the "default" security group.

[A decent walkthrough for the console](http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/)

[Amazon documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

[Rightscale explanation of different firewall situations](http://support.rightscale.com/12-Guides/Dashboard_Users_Guide/Clouds/AWS_Region/EC2_Security_Groups/Concepts/About_EC2_Security_Groups)

Comment: I did this. but no use